# Mysql query with count(distinct) show nothing if group by has no result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

I have a query on 3 tables, settlement, order and passenger.
A settlement has orders, and orders has passengers.

```
 TABLE: Settlemnt
    id


 TABLE: Order
    id     settlement_id


 TABLE: passenger
    id     orders_id
```

If settlement has no orders (and then no passengers), it returns nothing.
What I want, is to return the empty settlement even if it has no orders.
It is the count(passengers) that ruins it for me and returns no settlement if empty.
This is the simplified query:

```
  select s.id, o.id, count(distinct p.id) 
  from settlement s 
  left join orders o ON o.settlement_id = s.id 
  left join passenger p on p.orders_id = o.id
  where s.date = '2016-02-02';
  group by o.id
```

How can I make it return settlements with no orders?

Comment: So outer join passengers too.

Comment: nope, did not work :/

Comment: Of course it works. Consider providing an sqlfiddle

Comment: ok it worked here. strange it did not retrieve data in my java application or in mysql workbench...

Comment: I see you didn't learn much about formatting :-(

Comment: I found the error now, here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/548bc/1/0

Comment: The example has no GROUP BY clause. So I'm not sure of the relevance.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it works with the group by o.id. I will have to go back to my query again. Thank you

Comment: @Strawberry group by does not give me a group to count, so it will not return anything. Do you have another solution for how to count passengers?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me...

```
SELECT s.id s_id
     , o.id o_id
     , p.id p_id
  FROM settlement s
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.sid = s.id
  LEFT
  JOIN passengers p
    ON p.oid = o.id;
+------+------+------+
| s_id | o_id | p_id |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | NULL | NULL |
|    2 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a01b/4

Comment: @TorK Given the example above, what should the desired result set look like. Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with your query appears to be that you GROUP BY the o.id. Any settlement that has no order will have an o.id of NULL, hence all settlements with no orders will be lumped together into one row. Which s.id that is returned for this o.id is not defined (and effectively random).

Change it to GROUP BY both s.id and o.id

```
SELECT s.id, 
        o.id, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) 
FROM settlement s 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.settlement_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN passenger p ON p.orders_id = o.id
WHERE s.date = '2016-02-02';
GROUP BY s.id, 
        o.id
```